# Printing Error/Stopping Form Submission For Digits JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

Issue 1:

I'm trying to create a simple javascript function to check if all the characters entered into the field are numeric. The function is running, but not as I had hoped. I've located the `isNaN` function in javascript and it does not appear to be working. It enters the if statement every time, no matter if I type "asdf" or "1234" into the box.

Issue 2:

I want the form to stop submission obviously if the check for digits fails. However, I want it to continue to the submission page otherwise. I've been reading on ways to do this with pure JavaScript, and have the returns implemented as instructed. Is this a viable way to perform this? Alternatives?

Any help would be great on issue 1 or 2.

Here's my entire code:

```
<title>Bank System</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function checkNumeric()
        {
                var pin = document.getElementById('pin');
                if(isNaN(pin))
                {
                        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="Not A Valid Number";
                        return false;
                }
                else
                {
                        return true;
                }

        }




</script>

<body style="background-color: gray;">

        <h1>Welcome To Clayton's Credit Union</h1>
        </br></br>

        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></label>
                </br>
                <label>Pin Number<input type="text" maxlength="4" name="pin" id="pin"/></label>
                </br></br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onClick=" return checkNumeric()"/>
                <p id="message"></p>
                </br>

        </form>
```

*Please note, I know this is not secure in anyway. I'm making this example specifically to show how vulnerable it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an element to `isNaN` rather than it's value. Try this:

```
var pin = document.getElementById('pin').value;
```

**BTW**

You should run this validation on the form submit rather than the button click:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkNumeric()">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

instead of:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkNumeric()" />
```

Comment: @ZAX Glad to help. Also, I updated the `onclick` attribute in `form` tag to be `onsubmit`.